# confused about the way let reacts with loops

Tags: javascript, loops, variables

```
const OBJ = {
  MINNI : 79,
  TONU : 34,
  RITU : 23,
}

for(let a in OBJ)
  console.log(a,OBJ[a])

for(e of "abhi")
  console.log(e)
```

now let actually executes the blocked scooped variable from outside the bracket .. haven't we all have been told that let doesn't react to the under bracket variables ? without loops it will throw en error of variable being undefined .. let me know if you have answer of this one as i am much confused with this one

i were expecting that let won't react to the variable which is blocked scooped and yes it doesn't usually but with loops it is executing the code which is under the block

Comment: Minor note: `for(e of "abhi")` as shown above is relying on what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), you need to declare `e` for it not to be a global. If you wanted to contrast with `let`, you could use `var`, which would be scoped to the module or function it appears in (unless you're running this code at global scope, in which case it would also be a global, but at least not an implicit one).

Answer (score 2):

When you use `let` in a `for-in` (or `for`, or `for-of`) loop, the scope of the variable is the scope of the statement that forms the loop body. In your case, the loop body is `console.log(a,OBJ[a])`, so `a` is in scope and there's no problem using it.

You seem to think that the scope requires a block as the body of the loop, but it doesn't. This loop:

```
for(let a in OBJ)
  console.log(a,OBJ[a])
```

is the same as this loop:

```
for(let a in OBJ) {
  console.log(a,OBJ[a])
}
```

in terms of the scope of `a` (and in nearly all other ways).